# How do I mimic a native 404 page?

Tags: php, apache, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to 'soft shutdown' a website so users see an offline 404 page, but actually keeping the web server there.

Most of the solutions I found for 404 pages were creating custom (beautiful) 404 pages. I want to do the opposite: mimic a browser's stock (native) 404 page as close as possible.

So far I've tried the below.
In .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^ notfound.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and in notfound.php

```
http_response_code(404);
die();
```

The code works for Chrome and Firefox (showing a native 404 page), but Safari shows a blank (white) page instead. Is there a better way to address this?

Comment: For what reason do you want to this and what does speak against a regular or custom 404 error page? Don't reinvent the wheel.